# Filtering sniffed logs using Wireshark

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, wireshark, airport, sniffing

I'm experimenting with packet sniffing and log examination using Wireshark, and I'm quickly realizing that I'm not nearly as safe as I should be when using public hot spots. In efforts to better protect myself, I'm trying to learn the *tools of the trade* as it were, and figure out just what I'm leaking, and how to find it.

I have a 2011 Macbook Pro, and I'm using the `airport` command (Google will help you create a symlink if you're interested) to sniff packet data using my wireless card (`en1`) on a specific channel.

`sudo airport en1 sniff 6`

In 60 seconds I captured about 2MB worth of data. I live in an apartment complex, and a scan showed (unsurprisingly) that most of the networks were on channel 6, so that's the one I sniffed. (This is **also** the channel that my WiFi router uses.)

**But, to the question:** While I was sniffing the channel, I used a second device with WiFi to connect (unsecurely, HTTP) to Facebook and logged in. The goal for this exercise was to determine if I could find *my own password* stashed in the packets somewhere.

I tried using a few different filters in *Wireshark* to narrow down the traffic, but nothing seemed to match the filters I tried:

`http.request.uri matches "facebook"`

And also:

`ip.addr == 66.220.149.76` (This is the IP for `m.facebook.com`, I was using a smart phone.)

But no traffic seemed to match the filter. I'm very new to this, so I'm not sure which step I have fumbled.

1. Does it matter that my router does not broadcast an SSID?
2. Are my filters correctly formatted/defined?
3. Should I be scanning on a different channel? My router is specifically set to 6, not Auto or any other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted `http.request.full_uri`, which re-assembles the full URI by combining the contents of the HTTP `Host:` header with the URI from the from the `GET /some/uri/here HTTP/1.1` line.  You probably also wanted "contains" instead of "matches".

```
http.request.full_uri contains "facebook"
```

Don't waste time trying to filter on IP address unless it's a domain & host you control, and you know for sure that it only has one IP address.  Most well-known sites have multiple IP addresses.

You might also be interested in my answer over here: [Can other people on an encrypted Wi-Fi AP see what you're doing?](https://superuser.com/questions/156869/can-other-people-on-an-encrypted-wi-fi-ap-see-what-youre-doing/156969#156969)

Comment: Interestingly enough, that filter doesn't work either. I opened the packet file using TextWrangler and was able to search for "facebook" (and found a couple mentions of it) but WireShark still finds nothing when using any of the filters.